# extjs 6.2 throws TypeError: a is null and TypeError: contentEl is null

Tags: openlayers, geoext, ext-js

I am trying to setup my very first working basic example of a GIS using **GeoExt 3**, **Openlayers 4.4.1** and **ExtJS 6.2.0** within a **Symfony2.8.24** project.

The Symfony part I'm used to work with, I am trying to get the GIS part to work. I have gone through several posts and tutorials just to get this going and when thought I had finally figured out the dependencies I should include in my **html** file, I'm getting this error I don't even have a clue about. Actually, as you can see in the title, it's two errors, which correspond to `ext-all.js` and `ext-all-debug.js` respectively.

In other words:

1. If I include `ext-all.js`, then *TypeError: a is null* shows.
   [image: ext-all.js related error]
2. If I include `ext-all-debug.js`, then *TypeError: contentEl is null* shows.
   [image]

Code snippet from my `map.js` file containing the line which triggers the error:

```
var description = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            contentEl: 'description',
            title: 'Description',
            height: 200,
            border: false,
            bodyPadding: 5
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
            layout: 'border',
            items: [
                mapPanel,
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    region: 'west',
                    width: 400,
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                        align: 'stretch'
                    },
                    items: [
                        treePanel,
                        description // <-- THIS IS THE TROUBLESOME ONE
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
```

And this is the code snippet in `ext-all-debug.js` where the line with the error resides:

```
if (me.contentEl) {
    pre = Ext.baseCSSPrefix;
    hidden = pre + 'hidden-';
    contentEl = me.contentEl = Ext.get(me.contentEl);
    contentEl.component = me; // <-- ERROR RESIDES HERE
    contentEl.removeCls([
        pre + 'hidden',
        hidden + 'display',
        hidden + 'offsets'
    ]);
    me.getContentTarget().appendChild(contentEl.dom);
}
```

Could you tell me why this is happening??

Comment: Dependencies should go to `app.json` not to html files.

Comment: Did you follow the https://github.com/geoext/geoext3/blob/master/universal-app.md guide?